# Какие технологии использовать для шифровки данных при обмене

Tags: java, android, веб-программирование, сервер, криптография

Мне нужно, чтобы мое приложение обменивалось данными с веб сервером.Приложение написано на java. Какие способы существуют для шифрования информации при  обмене. знаю про SSL. Какие еще есть методы шифрования?

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает ssl? Не нужно изобретать велосипеды, особенно в криптографии

Comment: я в криптографии полный новичек, я читал, что в ssl заморочка с сертификатами,не подскажите, ssl хорошо подходит для описанного выше обмена данными?

Comment: Letsencrypt уже изобрели, так что получить сертификат не проблема. 90% сайтов которые вы посещаете (включая этот) используют https

Comment: не могли бы вы дать какие-либо источники с примером использования ssl в java, спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Без понятия, я на java не пишу, но на 146% уверен, что поход до веб-сервера по https это тривиальное действие описанное в каждом первом справочнике.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!